# Attempt to call a Udim2 value

Tags: lua, roblox

I am making a stamina bar for my game but I keep getting an Attempt to call Udim2 value error whenever I press LeftShift, I get the error. What is happening, could anyone please help? Here is the code:

```
    local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
    local charcter = player.Character

    local UserInputService = game:GetService("UserInputService")

    local Stamina = 100
    local running = false

    Stamina = math.clamp(Stamina, 0, 100)

    UserInputService.InputBegan:Connect(function(input)
        if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.LeftShift then
            running = true
            charcter.Humanoid.WalkSpeed = 22
            while Stamina > 0 and running do
                Stamina = Stamina-0.6
                
                script.Parent:TweenSize(UDim2.new(Stamina/ 100, 0, 1, 0) "Out", "Linear", 0)
                
                wait()
                if Stamina == 0 then
                    charcter.Humainoid.WalkSpeed = 16
                    
                end
            end
        end
    end)

    UserInputService.InputEnded:Connect(function(input)
        if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.LeftShift then
            running = false
            charcter.Humanoid.WalkSpeed = 16
            while Stamina < 100 and not running do
                Stamina = Stamina+0.5

                script.Parent:TweenSize(UDim2.new(Stamina/ 100, 0, 1, 0) "Out", "Linear", 0)
                 wait()
                if Stamina == 0 then
                    charcter.Humainoid.WalkSpeed = 16

                end
            end
        end
    end)
```

Comment: you're missing a comma `script.Parent:TweenSize(UDim2.new(Stamina/ 100, 0, 1, 0) "Out", "Linear", 0)`   after `)`  this results in an attempt to call the newly created UDim2 value with "Out" as argument...

Comment: you'll get further errors because it is probably `character` not `charcter` but as you definiet that variable that way that's ok. but it is definitely `Humanoid`, not `Humainoid`.  I stopped reading after that...  you cannot do any programming if you type that carelessly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is caused by a typo. You've forgotten to put a comma after each of your `UDim2.new` function calls :

```lua
UDim2.new(Stamina/ 100, 0, 1, 0) "Out",
```

The reason this is giving you an `Attempt to call a UDim2 value` error, is because of the lua language will allow you to call a function without parentheses when there is only one argument provided. For example, `print "hello world"` works exactly the same as `print("hello world")`. So because you've forgotten to put the comma after the UDim2 creation, the interpreter assumes that you're trying to call it like a function.

As for making a stamina bar, try something like this :

```
local UserInputService = game:GetService("UserInputService")
local RunService = game:GetService("RunService")

local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer

local stamina = 100
local maxStamina = 100
local running = false
local sprintCost = -0.6 -- per second
local sprintRecovery = 0.5 -- per second
local speedWalk = 16
local speedRun = 22

-- whenever the game ticks, update stamina
RunService.Heartbeat:Connect(function(deltaTimeS)
    -- quick escape if the player's character isn't loaded
    if not (player.Character and player.Character.Parent ~= nil) then
        return
    end

    -- quick escape if nothing is happening and nothing needs to be updated
    if stamina == maxStamina and (not running) then
        return
    end

    -- update stamina
    local change = if running then sprintCost else sprintRecovery
    stamina = math.clamp(stamina + (change * deltaTimeS), 0, maxStamina)

    -- set the run speed
    local isRunning = stamina > 0 and running
    player.Character.Humanoid.WalkSpeed = if isRunning then speedRun else speedWalk

    -- also keep the UI updated
    script.Parent.Size = UDim2.new(stamina / maxStamina, 0, 1, 0)
end)

-- when the user holds left shift, attempt to start running
UserInputService.InputBegan:Connect(function(input)
    if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.LeftShift then
        running = true
    end
end)

-- when the user lets go of left shift, stop running
UserInputService.InputEnded:Connect(function(input)
    if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.LeftShift then
        running = false
    end
end)
```

I moved your loop logic outside of the InputBegan and InputEnded handlers, and instead put it inside a [RunService.Heartbeat](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/event/RunService/Heartbeat) connection. This decouples the running logic from state changes, and it keeps your UI updated with every frame tick without needing to use Tweens. I also defined all of your magic numbers as variables near the top of the script, this will make it much easier to tweak values as you playtest.